# How to optimize WordPress speed

Tags: wordpress, optimization, pagespeed, w3-total-cache

[My WordPress website](http://nadiaakbar.com/) is slow (it loads in 6.9 seconds) and page size is 4.9 Mb.

I used GTmetrix to analyze my homepage:

[image: GTmetrix result page]

I think the major problem is with **defer parsing of JavaScript**.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two main reasons for your website to load very slow according to Google PageSpeedInsights:
[image]

Comment: but you have to tell Eliminate render-blocking resources /recaptcha/api.js?render=6LdjY8oUA…(www.google.com)
1 KB
230 ms
…minify/a73ca.css(nadiaakbar.com)
35 KB
190 ms
/css?family=…(fonts.googleapis.com)
1 KB
230 ms
…minify/2fd2b.css(nadiaakbar.com)
26 KB
230 ms
…minify/58cb5.js(nadiaakbar.com)  what the issues are that and a valid solution

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons that ring alarm bells, some of which might even cause major concerns for you.

First things first, you need to analyze the current load time for your website. Keep in mind that this speed may differ from page to page, as it depends on various factors, namely:

- *the size of that particular page,*
- *how many requests it generates,*
- *whether it is cached or not,*
- *and lastly, what kind of content (static or dynamic) it hosts.*

**For making it fast you can:**

- Choose a better web hosting provider
- Use a lightweight WordPress theme / framework
- Reduce image sizes
- Minify JS and CSS files
- Use advanced caching mechanisms with a caching plugin
- Use a CDN
- Enable GZIP compression
- Cleanup WordPress database

Comment: but the main reason is that how to defer parsing javascript of reCAPTCHA. i am using w3 total cache. you have to tell me perfect solution. I already, Reduce image sizes
enabled Minify JS and CSS files. but what do you mean by Use advanced caching mechanisms with a caching plugin

Comment: You can not defer reCAPTCHA, Analytics and Adwords files. But, you can use trick to show better scores in speed records